# How to choose DataTemplate with Triggers?

Tags: c#, wpf

I know that I can write `ItemTemplateSelector` to do this, but I wonder how to do it with triggers. I tried the following, but without success. It's probably because no `ItemTemplate` is set at the first place so no data on which triggers can be applied. Is it possible to do it with triggers?

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsAllowed}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" >
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                 ...
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsAllowed}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" >
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                 ...
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>        
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}" />
```

Comment: Can you give it a default setting before the trigger declaration? e.g. <Style TargetType...> <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">...</Setter><Style.Triggers>...

Comment: I don't think you can do it by changing the itemtemplate.  However, if you supply an item template with hidden elements, they can use the triggers to hide/unhide.

Comment: @failedprogramming, I tried it and it doesn't work. It uses the default settings and ignores the trigger.

Comment: @NebulaSleuth, why I cannot do it with triggers?

Comment: @theateist I'm not sure, it was a stab in the dark. My workflow is somewhat different to yours. If I just want to hide the itemscontrol, I would use a DataTrigger to manipulate the Visibility property instead of retemplating as you have done here. i.e. <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />. Of course you can also change other properties as needed. If the actual visual layout needs to be different, I would probably have separate viewmodels for allowed and not allowed, and have a seperate datatemplate for each.

Comment: @failedprogramming, I'm not hiding anything. For object with `IsAllowed=True` I want to show it as button for example. And for object with `IsAllowed=False` I want to show it as TextBlock for example. I define 2 different templates for data.

Comment: @theateist in that case you should have both the button and the textblock on the screen, both with identical databindings. If IsAllowed=True, button is shown and textblock is hidden.

Comment: @failedprogramming, it was just an example. I just wanted to know in general if I can do it with triggers. That's all! If not, I'd like to know why

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can.

Simply point the `Setter.Value` to a `StaticResource` that contains the `DataTemplate`, like so:

```
<Style
    TargetType='{x:Type ItemsControl}'>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger
            Binding='{Binding Path=IsAllowed}'
            Value='True'>
            <Setter
                Property='Background'
                Value='LightGreen' />
            <Setter
                Property='ItemTemplate'
                Value='{StaticResource TrueTemplate}' />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger
            Binding='{Binding Path=IsAllowed}'
            Value='False'>
            <Setter
                Property='Background'
                Value='LightCoral' />
            <Setter
                Property='ItemTemplate'
                Value='{StaticResource FalseTemplate}' />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And then declare both templates in your resources (`<UserControl.Resources>`). `TrueTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate 
    x:Key='TrueTemplate'>
    <StackPanel
        Orientation='Horizontal'>
        <TextBlock
            Text='{Binding Path=Name}' />
        <TextBlock
            Text=' ' />
        <TextBlock
            Text='{Binding Path=Surname}' />
        <TextBlock
            Text=', ' />
        <TextBlock
            Text='{Binding Path=Age}' />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

And `FalseTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate
    x:Key='FalseTemplate'>
    <StackPanel
        Orientation='Horizontal'>
        <TextBlock
            Text='{Binding Path=Age}' />
        <TextBlock
            Text=': ' />
        <TextBlock
            Text='{Binding Path=Name}' />
        <TextBlock
            Text=' ' />
        <TextBlock
            Text='{Binding Path=Surname}' />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

The template will be changed when the `IsAllowed` value is changed.

Comment: I was doubt that it would work, because I don't see any difference between what you wrote and I did. Anyway, I checked and it doesn't work.

Comment: Then check your output window for errors and double check your code. I suspect you have a binding error or a typo somewhere because, as I have checked it on my machine, this code really works. Does `IsAllowed` ever change? Is `INotifyPropertyChanged` correctly implemented?